# Removal of Appsettings values in Azure App Service and Blazor Server

Tags: azure, blazor, azure-web-app-service, blazor-server-side, azureportal

I’m pushing my first Blazor Server app out to an Azure App Service. As part of that, my appsettings has a couple entries in it along with the database connection string. I know that once it’s in Azure, I need to set the appsettings through the Configuration blade inside of the Azure portal which I have done and that all works. However, if I go look at the files through the Kudo tool, I can see the appsettings there along with the settings that I used for my local development.

I then tried a couple things to alleviate that. First, I tried removing the appsettings from my build pipeline. I was about to do that but when I do, I get a 500 server error in Azure. Adding the appsettings back it will then work again. Then I tried adding all of my settings to the appsettings.development.json and had my pipeline only remove that file and leaving a blank appsettings in the build. Again, that caused a 500 server error until I put it back.
What do I need to do in order to not have my appsettings published out to Azure or how do I hide my values if I have to keep the appsettings file in the build?

Side note in case this make a difference. This is how I’m calling for the appsettings value in my code.

Program.cs for connection string:

```
var connString = builder.Configuration["SqlConnection"];
```

Razor components:

```
IConfiguration config (DI injdected)
_config = config;

_config["GroupName"]
```

Appsettings

```
{
  "GroupName": "MyGroup",
  "SqlConnection": "xxxxxxxxxxx",
  "OIDC": {
    "Authority": "xxxxxxx",
    "ClientId": "IDName",
    "ClientSecret": "",
    "CallbackPath": "/Index"
  },
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*"
}
```

Comment: Could you please share your `appsettings.json` file.

Comment: And also plz share  the screen cap of azure app settings as well.

Comment: Added. The azure appsettings change to what I put in the Configuration blade which include Key Vault settings for connection string.  However, if I use Kudo and go look at the "Browse Directory / Site wwwroot" section, I can see appsettings.json as part of those files. If I open up the appsettings file from there, then I can see the exact same settings that I'm using locally which include direct connection string info.

Comment: You could use secrets.json for local dev and just keep the appsettings.json file with placeholder values i.e. `"SqlConnection": "Sql_Placeholder"` your secrets.json will take precedence over the appsettings for local dev and appsettings will be there to be overwritten by azure.

Comment: Yes..the values set in the app service configuration will override the values of appsettings.json file.

Comment: I use Visual Studio. It is as simple as right click your project and 'Manage user secrets`. Move your sensitive stuff there in the same format. Build a new publish profile and it should recognize you are using secrets. This will also keep your secrets out of the source repo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I can see the appsettings there along with the settings that I used for my local development.

Yes, you can see the local configuration values as well.
But as you have set the Configuration values in Azure App Settings, the local values of `appsettings.json` will be overridden with the Azure App Setting values.

So, there will be no problem with the local values.

> What do I need to do in order to not have my appsettings published out to Azure

If you don't want to publish `appsettings.json` file to azure, then change the properties of the file as below.

```cs
Build Action - None
Copy to Output Directory - Do not copy
```

[image]

- Below settings will be added in the `.csproj` file.

```cs
<ItemGroup>  
  <Content Remove="appsettings.json" />
</ItemGroup>

<ItemGroup>
  <None Include="appsettings.json">
    <CopyToOutputDirectory>Never</CopyToOutputDirectory>
  </None>
</ItemGroup>
```

- You can see that the `site\wwwroot` folder does not contain any configuration file.

[image]

- As there is no configuration file in the deployed app, then the output of the deployed app looks like below without any values.

[image]

- Once I set values in the Appsettings section,

[image]

Then the output will be

[image]

Thanks @Brian Parker and RBee for the comments.

As mentioned by Brian Parker, yes you can even set the secrets in the `secrets.json` file to work in local.

Comment: Thanks. Using the secrets.json works and I guess that's the way we will proceed going forward. I don't have to have the appsettings file removed necessarily as long as it doesn't contain any real values. However, I did test out the setting the properties to not copy the appsettings and that worked. I did have to manually add the settings in the .csproj file though but once I did, it worked as you said.