# Why are my AppSettings JSON files being included even after commenting them out of the configuration builder?

Tags: azure, .net-core, azure-web-app-service

I've been trying to migrate some of my app configurations from using appsettings.json files to use Azure App Configuration instead. Despite commenting out the .AddJsonFile extensions the app still seems to be using them to build the configuration.

I can't work out if I've missed some other setting besides the configuration builder setup that is causing the appsettings to be used.

I commented out the old .AddJsonFile extensions in the Main() method of my API and was expecting it to throw an error when trying to hit it.

Strangely it continued to function fine so I deleted the appsettings.json files on the server (under site/wwwroot), restarted the app service and then received the errors that I was expecting when I tried to hit it again. So it seems to me that the app service is still using the appsettings files to produce the configuration.

Here is what my Main() method looks like:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var env = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT");
            var configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                //.AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
                //.AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env}.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
                .AddAzureAppConfiguration()
                .Build();
}
```

I've scoured through the rest of the app and the app service to try see if there is some other setting that would be targeting the appsettings.json files but wasn't able to find any.

When trying to find similar questions online I only came across questions regarding people trying to *add* configuration via json files, and none where people were trying to *stop* using the json files.

The API is on .NET 7 (not using top-level statement) and hosted as a Web App on an Azure App Service.

Comment: Change the properties of the file to`Build Action - None` and Copy to output directory to `Do not copy`.

Comment: As it is already deployed to KUDU console and you can see teh file.So, first delete the file from the deployed files, make the changes which i have mentioned and redeploy the app again.Now you can see the file doesn't exist.

Comment: Refer the similar issue which I have addressed in [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77173541/removal-of-appsettings-values-in-azure-app-service-and-blazor-server/77178013#77178013)

Comment: @Harshitha I’m not trying to work out how to stop the appsettings from being copied into the app, I’m trying to understand why the configuration is trying to use them.

Comment: By default the app uses the available `appsettings.json` file. I think you have commented the code after 1st deployment.By that time the file is already available in the production environment.

Comment: Is the app picking the json file even after you delete the file in the deployed files? Have you redeployed the app ?

Comment: And how you are verifying that it is still picking the old json file?

Comment: If you are checking this in local after commenting, then do not forget to remove configurations from `appsettings.Development.json` file.

Comment: Please correct me if Iam wrong. `The app is working correctly ( not using old json files) in the deployed app and using json files in local`.

Comment: If you have `Environment Variables` => `App Settings` in the Azure App Service section, delete them as well.

Answer (score 0):

> Why are my AppSettings JSON files being included even after commenting them out of the configuration builder?

Once you deploy the app, the `appsettings.json` file will be available in the `root` folder of the deployed application.

- Even if you avoid it or as you said you commented, once after deployment the configuration file already exists in the production environment. So, the values will be picked from there.
- Any how you have deleted the file, but still, it is fetching the values from `appsettings` configuration.
- The reason can be the values are available in the Environment Variables.
- Even if we don`t have configuration in local or the deployed app and have the configuration setting in Environment Variable's. The app takes the values of the`  Environment Variables`=>`App Settings`.

[image]

- That is the reason your app is still using the App settings.
- Delete the key-value pairs and now run the app.
- To avoid confusion, make sure all the `appsettings json` files are deleted in the KUDU.
- If you have set the Environment as Development in Azure Portal and have `appsettings.Development.json` file in KUDU, then it will pick values from the existing file itself.